# Random Quiz Generator

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, graphing

I'm having issues with my code, i don't know how to get a random sample of the questions. This is the code and it keeps giving me a Key Error. Im trying to print a random question from the list of questions but its telling me that questions is a dictionary. Can anyone help me??

Here is the code

```
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random, math, csv

def read_database(filename):
    dictionary = {}

    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        q,a1,a2,a3,a4 = line.split(',')
        question = (q)
        answers = [a1,a2,a3,a4]
        dictionary[question] = answers
    infile.close()
    return dictionary

def read_results(outfile, score):
    player = {}
    outfile = open(outfile, "w")
    name = input("What is your name?")
    player[name] = score
    print(score, file = outfile)

    outfile.close()

def ask_question(question, answers):
    score = 0
    print(question[0])
    for multi in answers[1:5]:
        print(multi)
    answer = input("Please select an answer: ")
    print()
    if answer == answer[0]:
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect! - the correct answer was {0}.".format(answer[0]))
    print()
    return score

def main():
    questions = read_database("data.csv")

    score = 0
    score = int(score)
    print()
    print()
    print("=============================")
    print("Welcome to the baseball quiz!")
    print("=============================")
    print()
    print()
    name = input("What is your name?")
    number = int(input("Hi," + name + " there are {0} questions - how many do you want in your quiz: ".format(len(questions))))
    if number > len(questions):
        print("The quiz only has 10 questions, you will be asked 10 questions. ")
    else:
        print("You will be asked", number, "quesitons")
    key_list = random.sample(questions.keys(), number)
    #print(key_list)
    score = 0
    for key in key_list:
        print(key, questions.get(key))
        score = ask_question(questions, key)
        print(score)

    print("Your final score was {0} out of {1}.".format(score,number), score/100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is a sample of my data in a csv file:

> Who won the World Series this year?,The Cubs,The Mets,The Cardinals,The Indians
>
> How many players play defense on field?,Nine,Six,Ten,Twenty
>
> How many innings are in a baseball game?,Nine,Ten,Seven,Six

Comment: You are calling `ask_questions` with `questions` and `key` but it seems to expect one question and the answers as arrguments.

Answer (score 0):

The function `ask_question(question, answers)` needs to get the question and the list of possible answers as arguments.

Therefore you need to call it like this

```
score = ask_question( key, questions.get(key))
```

as in this case `key` is the question and the list of possible answers is `questions.get(key)`